# cannot load template after renewed template id

Tags: magento2

I am trying to set up a custom email template, it was work but shows an error after the template id is changed. May I know any way to fix it? Thanks!

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="custom_tabs" translate="label" sortOrder="110">
        <label>Email Tabs</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="email_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Custom Email send</label>
        <tab>custom_tabs</tab>
        <resource>Cleargo_ProductEnquiry::config</resource>
        <group id="sendmail" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Email Setting</label>
            <field id="enabled" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                <comment><![CDATA[Your Comments]]></comment>
            </field>
            <field id="sender" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="3" canRestore="1">
                <label>Product failed email sender</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
            <field id="email_template" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label>Custom Email Template</label>
                <comment>Email template chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>

</system>
```

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <email_section>
        <sendmail>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
            <sender>general</sender>
            <email_template>product_enquiry_email_template</email_template>
        </sendmail>
    </email_section>
</default>
```

app/code/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <email_section>
        <sendmail>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
            <sender>general</sender>
            <email_template>product_enquiry_email_template</email_template>
        </sendmail>
    </email_section>
</default>
```

Then I got the below error:

```
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Email template 'email_section_sendmail_email_template' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
2. In the left panel, expand **Email Tabs** and choose **Custom Email send**.
3. In the **Custom Email Template** field, choose your new email template, and click Save Config.
4. Clear the `config` cache type.